# Change the URL of the page without changing the page

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting

I want to change the page URL without changing the Page with `Javascript`, I want to completely change the URL including the Host Domain.

```
For example: Origional URL: http://host-one.com/page.html  
             New URL      : http://host-two.com/another-page.html
```

But not changing the contents.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: What's the point of changing the URL then without going to changed URL ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply: you can't.

The way that some sites (most notably Facebook) do it is to use anchors in the URL

**EDIT**

It seems you can in Chrome, Safari, FF4+, and IE10pp4+:

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: actually, no you can't.  The HTML5 method posted in the question you linked to only allows you to change the _path_ component of the URL, not the domain part.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this.

HTML5's `history.pushState()` allows you to change the *path* of the current URL, but not the domain.